# ROS2 IDE integration?

Tags: ros, ros2, ide

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
with the recent release of ROS2 dashing, I was asking myself if you can integrate ROS2 into an IDE like ROS1 and QRcreator or the ROS vscode plugin.  I'm not the most experienced Ubuntu user, but I had a good run with ROS1.
Is there a way of integrating ROS2? How should I debug my code instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325916/ros2-ide-integration?/) by [Jaymz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42853/jaymz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-06-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not a full integration yet, but [ros-industrial/ros_qtc_plugin#352](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_qtc_plugin/pull/352) adds initial ROS 2 / colcon support to the ROS-I Qt Creator plugin.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also use CLion and had a hard time to start with it. But it works perfect like this:

- Source your workspace
- Start CLion form the same terminal (usually /home/username/Applications/clion-2019.1/bin/clion.sh)
- Open CMake File as project
- Change in File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake:

1. CMake options: -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/username/workspace/devel (your devel folder of the workspace)
2. Generation path: /home/username/workspace/build (your build folder of the workspace)

---

Originally posted by [dofrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/33370/dofrey/) with karma: 38 on 2019-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2019-06-18**:
It is possible to have clion create a command-line launcher for you. If you installed with the Jetbrains toolbox app, it should do that automatically and you can just use `clion`. If you installed standalone, it should be under tools -> create command-line launcher (or something to that effect.)

**Comment by [dofrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/33370/dofrey/) on 2019-06-18**:
I actually never tried this. I still like to have the terminal open to launch my nodes. I found the option "create command-line launcher" but what is the effect of it and how do I create a launcher?
Do you know more about this?

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2019-06-18**:
When clion creates the command-line launcher it just puts a little script in your ~/.local/bin folder, which lets you start clion from terminal with just a `clion <folder_to_open>`. When developing, I usually `cd` to the workspace root, source things that I need to, and run `clion . &` (open current dir as a clion project) This way I still have a terminal open that has stuff sourced that I need, and now I have clion running that has all the ros stuff in it's PATH..

**Comment by [Tejas Kumar shastha](https://answers.ros.org/users/34361/tejas-kumar-shastha/) on 2019-10-16**:
It seems CLion requires a paid license beyond a 30 day evaluation period. Is there any other option with free IDEs? I did find [this page](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Building-ROS-2-on-Linux-with-Eclipse-Oxygen/) on the ROS website but it looks to be quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been using Clion for nearly all my ros1/2 development. The big thing is to start clion from a terminal that is sourced for your workspace. After that, I can right click on the `CMakeLists.txt` file for the package I need to work on, and select `Load CMakeLists.txt` Once that's done, I have access to all the code completion, suggestions, etc. I can build the package, run/debug, etc It works for both python and c++ nodes.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2019-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1